# What does "meint" mean here

Tags: german-to-english

It looks like in the sentence:

> "Meine Schwester meint, diese Show wird sich nicht lange halten".

The right English translation for *meint* is "say":

a) Is that correct?

b) If so would you provide another example where "meinen" means "say" and not "mean"?

This example just shook my belief that "meinen" might not be the exact translation of *mean* in English and might actually cover a broader range of meanings.

Comment: Per the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meinen), *meinen* may be a cognate to "mean" but they are not the same. The main takeaway here is don't trust cognates and always check a dictionary when in doubt.

Comment: There is perfect 1:1 translation in this context: "to opine" (not "say"!).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*say* is only one possible translation of [meinen](https://www.dict.cc/?s=meinen).

In this case, a better translation is *to be of the opinion* / or *to guess*.

*Meinen* can be used in the sense of I have no idea what you're talking about (*Ich weiß nicht, was du meinst*). The correct translation would then be *I don't know what you mean / I don't know what you're saying*

It can also be used to ask for an opinion or to express an opinion, then the translation would be, *to think*, *to guess*, ...  (*Meiner Meinung nach ist Star Wars langweilig, was meinst du?*)